# The name 'ViewData' does not exist in the current context

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, master-pages, viewdata, viewbag

I am working over my first application over MVC3 and still kind of a newbie in it:
I’m trying to success my ViewData[] over a master page because its contains a message that would be used over every page, but when I’m trying to access that it says:

*CS0103: The name 'ViewData' does not exist in the current context*

```
var msg = ViewData["msg"] as string;
        //var msg = ViewBag.msg as string;
        if (msg != null)
        {
            Response.Write (msg);
        } else if (msg == null)
        {
            Response.Write("");
        }
```

I am not sure whether I’m doing something wrong or it’s just not possible to access ViewData[] over my MasterPage. Help please!

Comment: BTW, you don't need your `if` check; `Response.Write(null)` wo't do anything.

Comment: ok but then how would i check that whether there is some message in ViewData or not? & if there is thn print it?

Comment: You don't need to check.  If you print a message that isn't there, nothing will happen,

Comment: ok Thanks! :) but i thnk ill still be using the     if as i am displaying a message in a div which will only be displayed if there is a message else it ll hidden.. so ild need to check if there is a msg or not!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set your master page to inherit `System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage`.

Comment: And stop using Response.Write. :)

Comment: it is currently been inherited by "myweb.Views.myweb" in master directive.. should replace it?
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="myweb.master.cs" Inherits="myweb.Views.myweb" %>

Comment: You should not use WebForms code-behind files in ASP.Net MVC.  Change it to `<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="ViewMasterPage" %>`

Comment: ok it has just started giving me this error:
"The type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage' is ambiguous:......"

Comment: You're probably referencing two versions of `System.Web.Mvc.dll`.  Remove one of them (check both `Web.config`s).  Read the entire message for more detail.